# How to use in memory (H2) Database in Node JS with express framework?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, h2, rdbms

I have some data from oracle table. I will be using H2 database to temporary store those data for unit testing.

Currently I am working on express API to connect to H2 Database for unit testing. What are the steps that I need to follow ?